# Headphones not working in windows 10 in HP ProBook 4530s

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers

Recently my headphones stopped working. My pc is an HP ProBook 4530s, with Windows 10 Pro 64bit installed. I'ts not a hardware problem since I have it dual boot with ubuntu, and in ubuntu everything works fine. HP official drivers are offered only until windows 8.1, and I installed it, and it didn't solve the issue. I also tried most of the several "solutions" found in youtube which involve changing the **Default Format** of the playback device in the advance properties tab, uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers (via windows driver update and hp official drivers offered in their costumer support site), and setting the headphones as the default device. I couldn't manage to set the headphones as the default device, but instead as the **default communication device**. Every time I try to set it as the default device, it just do nothing. Using windows troubleshooting wizard, it also tried to set the headphones as default device, but i got a message box saying that the wizard was unable to set the device as default. I'm using an administrator account, so it shouldn't be a permissions issue. I've not tried uninstalling any update, since I googled about them and none of the ones installed seem to have any known issues with sound. The following is my update history:

> ### Update History
>
> Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems (KB3124263)
>
> Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and Windows Server 2012, 2012 R2 x64 Edition - January 2016 (KB890830)
>
> Update for Internet Explorer Flash Player for Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems (KB3133431)
>
> Security Update for Internet Explorer Flash Player for Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems (KB3132372)
>
> Update for Windows 10 Version 1511 for x64-based Systems (KB3106246)

Please, help me out here... Although I'm very good at Linux systems administration, i really suck at anything windows related lol. any help will be appreciated, since I only have windows for gaming, and not being able to use headphones is a big issue.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here's the screenshot of the sound tabs:

[image: Sound Playback and Recording tabs]

Comment: What type of headphones are they? How do they plugin (USB/Jack)?

Comment: They are plugged in the front jack.

Comment: Can you press the `Windows` key on your keyboard and go to the `Sound` section in Windows (Found in the Control panel if search doesn't work). Screenshot both `Playback` and `Recording` options and post these in your original comment? I want to see what devices Windows thinks are installed.

Comment: Try disabling the second device under playback. Windows might be defaulting some of the applications to this device.  Also check the windows volume mixer (Right click volume > mixer) to see if any sound is coming from the applications. Does disabling the other device do anything?

Comment: It didn't work :(. I checked the mixer and there's sound being produced by several applications, but I can't hear anything in my headphones.

Comment: That's really unusual, Do you have the latest motherboard drivers installed? Does the Device Manager indicate if there's any drivers missing?

Comment: No, the device manager shows no drivers missing, and I also just in case uninstalled the audio drivers and installed the latest audio drivers from the HP site. I didn't try installing the motherboard drivers from hp. I'll do it, but the thing is that HP does not provide windows 10 drivers. I'll use the windows 8.1 ones.

Comment: Just installed the latest windows 8.1 chipset driver, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it happened that after a while, the problem fixed itself. It might be because of a new windows update. At first, there was a time when I turned the computer on and the headphones worked. Next time I turned the PC on, they didn't work, and after that time they have always worked, so it's kind of an erratic bug, but it seems microsoft fixed it!

Thanks anyways for your help, especially to **@Aaron Layfield**, who did his best trying to help me.